# Changing Dimensions of downloaded plot of plotly in r shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, plotly, r-plotly

I have a code which downloads the png image of the graph formed in plotly with same dimensions everytime. I want to generate a image with higher quality in it. Like if i click on the buttons provided at the top right corner in plotly graphs, it should download with different dimensions

Reference code is given below

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("choice", "Choose", choices = names(iris), selected = NULL),
  plotlyOutput("graph")
  )

server <- function(input, output, session){

  output$graph <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(iris, x = ~get(input$choice), y = ~Sepal.Length, type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers')
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `toImageButtonOptions` in the `config` function to set the dimensions:

```r
plot_ly(
  iris, x = ~get(input$choice), y = ~Sepal.Length, type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers'
) %>% config(
  toImageButtonOptions = list(format = "png", width = 1500, height = 750)
)
```